# Почему скрипт добавляет класс?

Tags: jquery

Привет!
Почему скрипт добавляет класс к body когда разрешение 1024?
По идее должно работать так, скрипт мониторит разрешение экрана, и при разрешении меньше 960 начинается работа.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 959) {
        $('.js-open-form, .b-menu__to-form').click('on', function() {
            $.browser_device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

            if ($.browser_device) {
                search_elementTop = $(document).scrollTop();
                $(function() {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                       scrollTop: search_elementTop
                    }, 500);
                });
            }

            $('body').addClass('active-form');

            $('.b-feedback-form').addClass('active');
        });

        $('.b-feedback-form__close-link').click('on', function() {
            $('.b-feedback-form').removeClass('active');
            $('body').removeClass('active-form');
        });
    }
});
```

UPD Работает вот так:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.js-open-form, .b-menu__to-form').click('on', function() {
        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 959) {
            $.browser_device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

            if ($.browser_device) {
                search_elementTop = $(document).scrollTop();
                $(function() {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                       scrollTop: search_elementTop
                    }, 500);
                });
            }

            $('body').addClass('active-form');

            $('.b-feedback-form').addClass('active');
            $('.b-feedback-form__close-link').click('on', function() {
                $('.b-feedback-form').removeClass('active');
                $('body').removeClass('active-form');
            });
        } else {
            $('.b-feedback-form').removeClass('active');
            $('body').removeClass('active-form');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте поставить условие проверки ширины внутри клика

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: @greybutton перенесите плиз свой ответ, что бы мог отметить, что вопрос решен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте условие проверки ширины внутри клика